# Melhor prática pra lidar com conjuntos de branchs no SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, html-tags, branch

Aqui na empresa utilizamos o SVN para versionamento. Temos o TRUNK que é disponibilizado para homologação antes de ir pra produção e gerar uma TAG, e temos também BRANCHS que simbolizam cada demanda. Até certo tempo atrás, cada BRANCH (demanda) terminada era simplesmente merged no TRUNK e disponibilizado pra testes e homologação, porém com a mudança de algumas gerências foi inserido o conceito de "pacotes", ou seja, as demandas só iriam subir pra teste/homologação em um conjunto de demandas/branchs (pacotes). No começo tudo era perfeito, mas com as ideias dos pacotes depois de um tempo começou a gerar problemas.

Ex:
Atualmente estamos trabalhando no TRUNK.12 que foi gerado a partir da release da TAG11, e a partir dele temos 3 BRANCHS que são as 3 demandas que serão desenvolvidas. Depois das branchs terem sido finalizadas são "mergeds" no TRUNK e testadas pela HOMOL, mas certas vezes algumas dessas demandas (branchs) não são aprovadas e/ou canceladas, e volta pra gente.

Acabamos ficando com um Trunk com as 3 branchs e devemos tirar 1 ou mais delas.

Qual a melhor maneira de lidar com esse problema? Reverter o Trunk novamente pra TAG da release 11? Essa é a melhor opção?

P.s. Desculpa se não ficou tão claro, foi a melhor maneira que consegui explicar sem adicionar dados mais específico da empresa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse é um dos motivos pela qual o SVN foi sendo abandonado em detrimento do uso do GIT.

Como o SVN é um repositório CENTRAL e todos usam apenas referencias locais controlar alterações em equipe vai se tornando complexo.

Na sua pergunta, até o ponto de gerar um branch 12 a partir da TAG 11 está tudo OK.

As minhas experiências com o SVN para casos semelhantes ao seu me levaram a seguir as seguintes regras:

- Entender que deve haver apenas um responsável pelos **MERGES** no **TRUNK**
- O que deve ser homologado não é o **TRUNK** e sim o **BRANCH** com o assunto.
- Cada desenvolvedor DEVE ter um BRANCH particular e ao final todos devem dar MERGE no BRANCH do **ASSUNTO** e não no TRUNK, apenas ao final da homologação é que o se deve dar merge no TRUNK e gerar uma nova TAG.

Lembre-se, não existe o caminho correto para o versionamento e sim as melhores práticas que funcionem em um determinado caso.

Aqui tem umas dicas de recomendações: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/user/svn-best-practices.html

Comment: O único problema nesse caso é que o TRUNK necessariamente precisa ir pra homologação, por algum motivo desconhecido que ninguém soube me explicar direito é no TRUNK que é feito as validações do SONAR, testes e etc... :(

Comment: Muito bom isto, pura classe e tipo resposta canônica pra pergunta "qual o melhor xyz pra fazer abc": *`Lembre-se, não existe o caminho correto para o versionamento e sim as melhores práticas que funcionem em um determinado caso.`*

Comment: @brasofilo, não entendi seu comentário e no que ele ajuda a chegar na solução. Com versionamento não existe o **CORRETO**. Se por acaso se deu ao trabalho de ler a página das boas práticas tem umas frases lá bem interessantes como _This is a hotly debated question, and it really depends on the culture of your software project._  ou _There are many ways to lay out your repository_. 
A resposta menciona uma forma de se trabalhar versionamento porem utilizando o GIT e não o SVN. Trabalhei anos com SVN e MERGE sempre foi um parto, o que não acontece com o GIT.

Comment: Estava elogiando esse trecho que acho fundamental quando se fala de "melhores práticas". Pode sinalizá-lo como "não-construtivo" e um moderador deleta sem problemas...

Answer (score 1):

Como você tem as 3 demandas que foram feitas apartir da TAG12, então temos que elas estão separada cada uma em 1 novo branch, como ja foram feitas o Merge para o Trunk provavel que o TortoiseSVN não deixe fazer por conta de ser um Merge, pelo menos o TortoiseHG não deixa.

Você tem 2 opções:

1. Com os commits da 2 demandas que não foram aprovadas, reverter commit a commit. Dê update na Trunk, então reverta cada commit dos 2 branchs não aprovados.
2. Crie um novo ramo de Trunk antes da Mesclagem das 3 demandas com um nome adquado, então mescle a demanda aprovada e continue, assim que as outras 2 forem aprovadas mescle nesse ramo que ja foi Homologado, então esse ramo novo que criou apartir da trunk para estabilizar, mescle novamente para a trunk.

**Possível solução para não acontecer mais (não existe uma forma correta):**

Utilize o modelo de Vincent Driessen:

> [***A successful Git branching model***](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)
>   *In this post I present the development model that I’ve introduced for all of my projects (both at work and private) about a year ago, and which has turned out to be very successful. [...] I won’t talk about any of the projects’ details, merely about the branching strategy and release management. It focuses around Git as the tool for the versioning of all of our source code.*

Não sei se vocês aplicam alguma metodologia agil, porém somente faz a mesclagem de Demandas para a trunk, ou no modelo que sugeri, quando for aprovada pela homologação, cliente, gerente de projeto, product owner, etc. Ou seja, somente colocar para homologar a versão se for dado o "Aceite".

Comment: Como comentei ali na outra resposta, por motivo desconhecido o que vai pra homolagação pra ter o "aceite" tem que ser necessariamente o TRUNK que passa pelo SONAR e outras validações. Depois de tudo certo já gera a Tag com a versão de release